# Allennlp Does not generate model.tar.gz after training

Tags: python, nlp, allennlp, coreference-resolution

I am training a coreference resolution model with Alennlp. However after I execute the command `train_data_path=<train path> validation_data_path=<dev path> test_data_path=<testpath> dataset_reader=<dataset reader> allennlp train <jsonnet file> -s <output dir> --include-package <training module>`
it does not produce a `model.tar.gz` file in the `<output dir>`.

Any idea why?

edit: I've been running this via polyaxon and somehow the error logs does not appear after it fails. Rightfully once training completes the model.tar.gz file should appear. I think it should be an error that appears during training that fails it but I am unable to inspect it

Answer (score 1):

The `Train` subcommand will always produce the `model.tar.gz` archive so long as (1) `--dry-run` is not supplied to the CLI; and (2) the training process ran to completion without error (cf. [code](https://github.com/allenai/allennlp/blob/dd5a010ebd3a2e8f2402de1374f782ed7f10d032/allennlp/commands/train.py#L344L347)). You likely are having an error during training that needs to be corrected.